# блокировка api запроса к steam api

Tags: api, steam, steam-web-api

После 10-12 запросов к api перестал приходить ответ

```
url = "https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/ID/730/2?count=1000"
response = requests.get(url)

items = []

if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    descriptions = data.get('descriptions')
```

Но если выполнять запрос через строку браузера, то ответ приходит исправно. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема, заранее благодарен!

Comment: скорее всего есть ограничения самой `api` дабы не ддосили ее. Ищите информацию на их официальных сайтах по api или пишити в сапорт с данным вопросом, чтобы узнать конкретику (сколкьо можно, за какое время и т.д.). Вроде на форумах пишут 10 запросов в минуту (но это не точно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе главное было не спамить запросами, как я в свою очередь этим грешил, привычка, сделать мелкую правку в коде и перезапустить страницу, вышла боком.